# SSRS Tool Tip Flashing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having an issue with a flashing tool tip on text where the writing mode has been changed to Rotate270. By flashing I mean, that the tool tip does not appear when you hover over the text box, but only when you hover over the actual text in the text box. At that time the mouse pointer changes to a flashing cursor and the tool tip flashes with it.

This does not happen on horzontal text, the issue only happens when the writing mode has been set to Rotate270.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I confirm that I had this issue before. You can always generate an image with the text IF you really need a 270 degree text WITH a tooltip.

Comment: I also had this issue. The solution for me was to add empty text label on top of the rotated text and defining the TT on this label.